# Can't mass-assign protected attributes spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, attr-accessor

I just added a new column called coverimage to my table.

Used it in _form for users to post a link, I'm getting the following error.

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: coverimage
```

usually I would just to attr_accessor :coverimage on the model, but since I am using the static_pages gem, I can't locate the model on the app, this is what my gemfile looks like.

```
gem 'spree_static_content',  github: 'spree/spree_static_content',         branch: '1-3-stable'
```

is there a workaround or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails '3.2.18'

Comment: you can allow mass assignment by setting config.activerecord.whitelistattributes to false in your config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb file